# How to implement clickonce using Apache on windows

Tags: visual-studio, apache2, clickonce, publish

I am trying out click-once on my local machine using Apache 2.2.

I have added following to httpd.conf

```
AddType application/x-ms-application .application
AddType application/manifest .manifest
AddType application/octet-stream .deploy
AddType application/octet-stream .msp
AddType application/octet-stream .msu.
```

I have given the publishing folder and the installation folder path to http://localhost. I am using vs2008 with 3.5 SP 1. When, I click publish I am getting this error

```
Error   23  Failed to connect to 'http://localhost/' with the following error:     Unable to open the Web site 'http://localhost/'. To access Web sites on the local IIS Web server, you must run Visual Studio under an Administrator account in order to have access to the IIS metabase. Alternatively, install FrontPage Server Extensions (FPSE) and then grant FPSE access to users who will run Visual Studio.
```

Please let me know what am I missing?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a network share (e.g. *\\localhost\publish-folder*) or a local folder (e.g. *C:\publish-folder*) as *Publishing Folder Location*. Visual Studio must have write access to this location.

[image]

Comment: where this folder should be created?

Comment: @jess You can create it anywhere you want. Try a simple *c:\temp* first to see if publishing works. Then you can change it to a subdirectory under the `DocumentRoot` directory so every time you publish the project new files are automatically served by Apache.

Comment: does DocumentRoot means, under apache installation folder? I am getting this error Launching Application.
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697210'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'http://abc/my.application', when I run setup.exe

Comment: @jess What did you use as *Installation Folder URL*? Did you use `http://abc`? `DocumentRoot` is *a directory that forms the main document tree visible from the web* http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot - this is where Apache looks for files to serve (i.e. make available under http://localhost/ or whatever URL you use). *Apache installation folder* is `ServerRoot`, but I have no idea what are default values of `DocumentRoot` and `ServerRoot` under Windows.